# Awk Sum skipping Special Character Row

Tags: awk

I am trying to take the sum of a particular column in a file i.e. column 18.
Using awk command along with Printf to display it in proper decimal format.

```
SUM=`cat ${INF_TARGET_FILE_PATH}/${EXTRACT_NAME}_${CURRENT_DT}.txt|awk -F"" '{s+=$18}END{printf("%24.2f\n", s)}'
```

Above command is skipping those rows in file which has the special character in one of the column 5 - RÉPARATIONS. Hence Awk skips these rows and doesnt consider sum for that row. Please help how to resolve this issue to take sum of all rows.

Comment: Is it *skipping* them, or does the encoded file (UTF-8? ISO8859-1? how is the file encoded to allow non-ASCII characters?) cause awk to mis-count fields?  Try grabbing just the lines in question and seeing whether `$18` is what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

There is missing a back tics in your example, should be:

```
SUM=`cat ${INF_TARGET_FILE_PATH}/${EXTRACT_NAME}_${CURRENT_DT}.txt|awk -F"" '{s+=$18}END{printf("%24.2f\n", s)}'`
```

But you should not use back tics, you should use parentheses `$(code)`
Using cat to enter data to `awk` is also wrong way to do it, add pat after `awk`

```
SUM=$(awk -F"" '{s+=$18} END {printf "%24.2f\n",s}' ${INF_TARGET_FILE_PATH}/${EXTRACT_NAME}_${CURRENT_DT}.txt)
```

This may resolve your problem, but gives a more correct code.
If you give us your input file, it would help us to understand the problem.